# Install ingres extension for PHP on a debian server

Tags: php, installation, debian, pecl, ingres

I've to work with a ingres database for my php server.

I just have one question:

I will never connect myself on an ingres server locally, is it still mandatory to install ingres locally to install ingres?

I tried to install ingres with PECL:

```
    pecl install ingres
downloading ingres-2.2.2.tgz ...
Starting to download ingres-2.2.2.tgz (92,203 bytes)
.....................done: 92,203 bytes
10 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Ingres II_SYSTEM dir? [/opt/Ingres/IngresII] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/ingres-2.2.2
running: /tmp/pear/temp/ingres/configure --with-ingres=/opt/Ingres/IngresII
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for improved Ingres support... yes, shared
checking Use ingres2 as the extension name... no
configure: error: Cannot find iiapi.h under /opt/Ingres/IngresII/ingres/files - is $II_SYSTEM set?
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/ingres/configure --with-ingres=/opt/Ingres/IngresII' failed
```

It gives me the impression that it tries to access to some ingres files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ingres PHP extension is written using Ingres's OpenAPI interface. That API requires a local Ingres client be installed on the machine where you're making the connection from. In order to build the extension you need to have the `II_SYSTEM`environment variable setup, pointing to your local Ingres client. Once you have that you can run

`sudo II_SYSTEM=${II_SYSTEM} pecl install ingres`

or run through the steps outlined in http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/ingres/trunk/README.html#unix

If you are logged in as root already, make sure II_SYSTEM is defined before executing:

`pecl install ingres`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it with root rights, because this extension tries to install into /opt/Ingres/IngresII folder.

So try to run `sudo pecl install ingres`

Comment: I'm logged with the root user to do this install

Comment: Eugene, you have to set II_SYSTEM so pecl can find OpenAPI header files... Grant gave the correct way of installing the Ingres extension. After all, he is the author of it. :)